# How to make a bounce feedback when jumping on head of enemy Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm trying to develop a little enemy, that would make me damages and could be killed by jumping on it. For those two points, I did it, and it does work well. However, when I'm jumping on the head of an enemy, defined by a collider with trigger, I want to make it more responsive, with my player to jump a little bit, such as in Mario for example.

If you need any other informations on names and others, don't hesitate !

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HeadDetect : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Enemy;
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3F;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Update()
    {
        Enemy = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
        if (Enemy.transform.position.y < -15)
            Destroy(Enemy.gameObject); 
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision) {
        if(collision.tag == "Player") {
            // Killing of the enemy (flipY and falling on void)
            Enemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 10;
            Enemy.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = true;
            GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
            Enemy.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
            Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Random.Range(40, 70), Random.Range(-40, 40), 0f);
            Enemy.transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime;
            // End of kill

            // A try I gave to make this jump smooth, not working
            Vector3 targetPosition = collision.GetComponent<Transform>().TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, 4, 0));
            collision.GetComponent<Transform>().transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(collision.transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried to make it more responsive? Please include your research.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the velocity on the colliding rigidbody? Something like `Rigidbody2D otherRb = Collider2D.attachedRigidbody; Vector2 otherVel = otherRb.velocity; otherVel.y = 1f; otherRb.velocity = otherVel;`

Comment: Where could I do that ine the program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `SmoothDamp` in `OnTriggerEnter`. It needs to be run every frame during the bounce. So for example you can do something like this to get the smooth damp to work:

```cs
public void Update()
{
    if (bounce)
    {

        // insert your smooth damp functionality here every frame

        if (bounceComplete)
        {
            bounce = false;
        }
    }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter(...)
{
    bounce = true;
}
```

However, consider this way also

```cs
public void OnTriggerEnter(...)
{
    rigidbody.velocity += Vector2.up * bounceSpeed;
}
```

Then rigid body physics can simulate the rest.

(I have left out variable initializations, but ask if something is unclear)